# Drop down if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I add a if statement to this?

> <%= f.select(:manager_user_id, User.all.collect {|user|
>   [user.full_name, user.id]}.sort{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}, :prompt =>
>   "Select a Project Manager") %>

it needs this to check that the user has role ProjectManager

```
if user.has_role? :ProjectManager
```

Comment: You want the select to appear only if user is ProjectManager? or you want to list all users that are Project Managers?

Comment: I want the select to show all project managers

Comment: You don't add an if statement, you select only users that are project managers.

Comment: @Ahmet Yeah, I'd re-visit your accepted answer--you really don't need to select all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.select(:manager_user_id, User.all.select { |user| user.has_role?(:ProjectManager) }.collect {|user| [user.full_name, user.id]}.sort{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}, :prompt => "Select a Project Manager") %>
```

Comment: Of course this is totally wrong because it will fetch all the Users from the DB. You should definitely not go this way. I am adding a modified answer of @alassiter just to make it correct.

Comment: This answer is the first idea came to my mind when i sea the question.Now i realize it will cause performance issues.I accept that your answer is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, I would set up a scope in the user model:

```
scope :project_managers, where(...)
```

Then you can say

```
<%= f.select(:manager_user_id, User.project_managers.select { |user| user.has_role?(:ProjectManager) }.collect {|user| [user.full_name, user.id]}.sort{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}, :prompt => "Select a Project Manager") %>
```

I think that's right. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :project_managers, where(...)
end
```

Then in your view write

```
<%= f.collection_select(:manager_user_id, User.project_managers, :full_name, :id, :prompt => "Select a Project Manager") %>
```

If you want to sort just do it in your scope or in your instance method `:project_managers`